# Pinescript Strategy Tester TIME range

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I’ve managed to pretty much write a whole strategy on TradingView with a time stamp that is able to filter out a range of dates for example 1st January 2023 to 17th January 2023 and backtest my strategy within these days.

I wanted to find out if there is a way to make this strategy even better by selecting a real time range. For example only trade between 08:30am and 13:00pm on the days within the date range.

This is probably really long winded for what I’m asking.

TL;DR
How do I add a time range (HH:MM) to my strategy so backtested trades are within a certain time

I’ve searched online but can’t find anything apart from a day range, however, I’m looking for a time range within this day range.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `session`.

You can do it by getting a `session` input from the user and checking if the current time is within that time window.

An example from the [F.A.Q](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-track-highslows-for-a-specific-period-of-time):

```
timeAllowed = input.session("1200-1500", "Allowed hours")
timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":1234567")
```

Then use `timeIsAllowed` as your entry and/or your exit condition.

Comment: TimeAllowed looks promising & will attempt to add that to the script & attempt to run it. 

I’m not quite understanding the TimeIsAllowed part of your response though.

Comment: It will only be `true` if you are within the selected session. So, you can use it as an additional condition to enter a trade.

Comment: Sent mail message